# which IAM role is required to connect dynamodb from ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

In Amazon AWS services:

I have created EC2 instance and some tables in DynamoDB.
I am able to do operations via console on dynamoDB but unable to connect dynamo database with command line.

one option is to configure AWS service by '**aws configure**' command and pass access key ID etc.

Other option is to provide IAM role to EC2 instance.
when i provide all access it works well but i want to know specific access or IAM role should given to EC2 instance for connecting dynamoDB CLI from EC2.

Thanks

Comment: You need to create custom access role :- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/using-identity-based-policies.html

Answer (score 2):

Create a new IAM role with EC2 as trusted entity. Add policy to give dynamodb access to this role. Following policy will give full permission to dynamodb.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DescribeQueryScanBooksTable",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "dynamodb:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new EC2 role and attach the policy "AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess" if you want full DB access else add the granular permissions you want while attaching the policy.